# Multiple TextToSpeech instances with different languages

Tags: android, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

I'm keeping two instances of a `TextToSpeech` with different languages in order to make the device pronunce in different languages depending on the pressed button.
I'm doing this because changing the language on the same `TextToSpeech` is a long task and introduce remarkable lags.
Now my problem is that, also with these two instances the lag still remains!

I want to be able to pronunce a word in different languages with no delays, how can I achieve that?

Comment: I'm not sure that you can.  A spoken language model takes up a lot of memory.  Most likely the built in version is programmed to only hold one in memory, as its all 99% of people need.  That means switching languages requires the old one to be kicked out of memory and the new one to be loaded from disk, causing lag.  I think your only possible solution is either writing or finding a custom text to speech app you can put in your application that can be made to support multiple models in memory at once.

Comment: I've done some tests and I think you are right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering my own question because, thanks to the Gabe's comment, I've done some test and I've come to the conclusion that it is not possible two load two different languages with the default Android TextToSpeech because of the large amount of memory that it requires.